# Open a Different Activity While Launching

Tags: android, android-activity, installation

I have one Application named Application A, while installing Application A, I want to Open Activity A and While Clicking launcher icon I want to open Activity B. Is this possible? Can anyone help on this?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with SharedPreferences. Use a boolean, at first run you will have to set that boolean to true and it will be saved locally on your phone. Inside your MainActivity or your Application class(if you have one), do a check and start Activity A if boolean is false otherwise start Activity B.